# Windows scheduled task run with delayed start

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file which is set to run as a Scheduled Task on Windows Server 2008 SP2.

The content of the batch file is as below:

```
cscript ".\Scripts\ProcessImport.wsf" > .\Logs\Import.log
```

The task is scheduled to run at 02:00 and 16:30 every day. The 02:00 run is always delayed by at least a couple of hours but the 16:30 run always starts on time.

I have deleted and recreated the task but the issue persists.

The scheduled task settings that have been selected are:

1. (General) Run whether user is logged on or not
2. (Conditions) Start the task if only the computer is on AC power Stop if the computer switches to battery power
3. (Settings) Allow task to be run on demand
4. (Settings) Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days
5. (Settings) If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop.

There is nothing else running on the server around that time and still it is delayed.

Has anyone faced a similar issue before and fixed it?

This is my task:

```
"HostName": ""
"TaskName": "\RunETL_2am"
"Next Run Time": "3/02/2018 2:00:00 AM"
"Status": "Ready"
"Logon Mode": "Interactive/Background"
"Last Run Time": "2/02/2018 3:31:44 AM"
"Last Result": "0"
"Author": ""
"Task To Run": "Multiple actions"
"Start In": "Multiple actions"
"Comment": "Runs all three ETLs Export, Transform, Load in single job. The Transform and Load scripts/processes are built to wait for the previous job to finish before they start doing anything."
"Scheduled Task State": "Enabled"
"Idle Time": "Disabled"
"Power Management": "Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries"
"Run As": "*"
"Delete Task If Not Rescheduled": "Enabled"
"Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins": "72:00:00"
"Schedule": "Scheduling data is not available in this format."
"Schedule Type": "Daily "
"Start Time": "2:00:00 AM"
"Start Date": "31/01/2018"
"End Date": "N/A"
"Days": "Every 1 day(s)"
"Months": "N/A"
"Repeat: Every": "Disabled"
"Repeat: Until: Time": "Disabled"
"Repa Until: Duration": "Disabled"
"Repeat: Stop If Still Running": "Disabled"
```

Comment: Could you provide some additionals informations ? What are the settings of your Scheduled Task?

Comment: Without at least providing the batch file content, this is a "I am having an issue with a scheduled task not running at its designated time" question and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp: The scheduled task settings that have been selected are: 
1. (General) Run whether user is logged on or not 
2. (Conditions) Start the task if only the computer is on AC power
    Stop if the computer switches to battery power
3. (Settings) Allow task to be run on demand
4. (Settings) Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days
5. (Settings) If the running task does not end when requested, forvce it to stop.

Comment: You are absolutely positive you do not have a delay set in the Advanced Settings for that specific Trigger at 2am?  I sure would like to see the Task History as well.

Comment: What about the wake if sleeping setting?

Comment: I have added your information from the comments to your question body, you may now delete those comments.

Comment: If there's only one line in your batch file, would it not make sense to use full paths instead of relative ones? That way, it wouldn't matter under which user context, _(working directory)_, it is run, the locations will be assured.

Comment: please add the output of `schtasks /query /v /fo csv|find "YourTaskName"` to your question.

Comment: @Stephan:  "**","\RunETL_2am","3/02/2018 2:00:00 AM","Ready","Interactive/Background","2/02/2018 3:31:44 AM","0","**","Multiple actions","Multiple actions",
"Runs all three ETLs Export, Transform, Load in single job. The Transform and Load scripts/processes are built to wait for the previous job to finish before they start doing anything."
,"Enabled","Disabled","Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries","*","Enabled","72:00:00","Scheduling data is not available in this format.","Daily ",
"2:00:00 AM","31/01/2018","N/A","Every 1 day(s)","N/A","Disabled","Disabled","Disabled","Disabled"

Comment: @ACatInLove - I have enabled this now and will see how it goes.

Comment: The 2 AM job started on time yesterday but it did not start until 0330 AM today. The Task Category for this job shows: Task triggered on scheduler at 03:31:44 AM.

Comment: Look in Event Viewer for `Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter` events.